# Struggling with a proof when $x > 0, x > a$, then $x > a$

Tags: proof-writing

This is coming from a question in spivak's calculus, solving $(x-1)(x-3) > 0$.

There are two cases where this is true, when both brackets are positive, or when both are negative.

But when I look at the positive case, I get $x>1, x> 3$.

I know intuitively that the only valid $x$ values where both are true is when $x > 3$. But can't seem to be able to prove it.

I realize that I should try and get a general proof for when $x> 0, x > a$, then $x > a$.

But i've tried for the last couple days and I haven been able to get anything remotely on a good track.

Can anyone give me a solution, or maybe some hints in the right direction?

Comment: If $x > a$, then $x > a$??? Maybe I'm missing out on something here...

Comment: You could prove "if $x>3$, then $x>1$" by contrapositive pretty easily if you really want to fully flush it out with a proof technique. Or just prove it directly (even more easily). But I really don't think this is something that it's necessary to prove...

Comment: why don't you take the intersection $(3,\infty)\cap(1,\infty)$?

Comment: You actually need $$x>a,x>b\implies x>\max(a,b)$$ For the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only logical solution is $x \gt 3$. You are right. And that is it. There is no need to prove this identity.

Say you are given that $x \gt a$ and $x \gt 0$. By *solving* this  what you are require to do is to find a set of values for  which both inequalities are satisfied. Clearly, $x \gt \text{Max} \{ 0, a \}$. That is it. It is intuitive and it is the only solution. This is what you have arrived at for the exercise too. There is no need to *prove* it.

Obvious is a word I hate to use in Mathematics. But in your case it seems appropriate. Stop overthinking is another advice.

Hope I helped.

**EDIT:** 
I checked the book out. Can't believe I forgot all of this. Maybe this would help.
$x \gt 1 \implies (x - 1) \in P \implies x \in (1, \infty)$ and $x \gt 3 \implies (x- 3) \in P \implies x \in (3, \infty)$ where $P$ is the set of all positive numbers as per the definition in the text.

For both inequalities to be satisfied $x \in (1, \infty) \cap (3, \infty ) = (3 , \infty)$

Comment: well to be fair, it *is* obvious. it really "grinds my gears" when people try to prove obvious stuff.

Comment: Spivak's calculus is an 'introduction to analysis' text book. It teaches you to complete proofs throughout the textbook, building up from only one axiom. I am sure he is just following the exercises as listed.

Comment: I know it's obvious, I just thought there might be a proof to it, because the whole point of the chapter of the book I'm using is to prove very basic things from a set of assumptions; where that was not listed

Comment: Ah, the above commenter beat me to it

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the edit was really valuable for me

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a proof:

We need to prove that $x>$ Max$(0, a)$ given that $x > 0$ and $x>a$ for $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Since $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $a > 0$. So, Max$(0, a) = a$. Therefore, we only need to show that $x > a$. But, we already know that $x > a$, so we're done.